# Can I use the VS2012 Quick Launch to open a file from my solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

VS2012 added a new Quick Launch edit box in the title bar. Is there a key sequence I can use to open an arbitrary file from the solution?

I want something:

- fast
- keyboard only
- that doesn't care where in my solution the file lives

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is "**no**" but I found a different way to do the same thing: <kbd>ctrl-;</kbd>. This does "search in Solution Explorer". It incrementally searches files **and** symbols.

[image]